# How to make an async call to webserver when my app opens

Tags: android

I need to make an async call to a webserver whenever I open my app, even if I bring it from the background to the front. How do i do this in Android?

The async task is not a problem, it's a simple request to a server with no response, it just needs to tell the server that the app has been opened.

I've tried using the `BaseActivity.onResume()` method but it doesn't work because it is called every time a new activity is opened.

Comment: can you share your code ?

Comment: so you don't want it in when activity created, you just want to call asynctask whenever activity comes in state of Resume after first launch , right ?

Comment: you could try to extend the `Application` and put your call to `onCreate()`  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

Comment: i've tryed extending application but it doesnt work. if i put it in onCreate() it will only launch the asycn call when the application is created for the first time. that not whta ii want.

Comment: @Aafaq yes. source code wont help. because the problem isnt the asycn task but its conceptional

Answer (score 0):

okay I think this can solve your problem with only a single flag :)

> boolean isFirstLaunch=true;

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            isFirstLaunch = false;
        }
```

and here is onResume()

```
@Override
protected void onResume()
        {
            if(!isFirstLaunch)
                runAsyncTask();
            super.onResume();
        }
```

Comment: yes this is half of the problem. when and how do u reset the isFirstLaunch flag to true again? because when the application goes to the background this needs to be set to true. and wehn the application is brought again to the foreground the asycn call should be called!

Comment: just implement this, it'll true when activity is created

Comment: and what do you mean by background, in pause status or you are using service ?